# query is not fetching all the results in related tables

Tags: php, symfony

In my symfony test project I have two tables whereby users is related to flight. Flight has fk to users in this structure

```
users

id | name | email |
1  | fen  | f.com |
2  | foo  | o.com |

flight
id | path | desc | dureation | users|
1  | 123  | xyz  | 3         | 1
```

I am using below query in a repository to pull for all the data where user id is 1.

```
class FlightRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function findWithFlights($id)
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->join('u.flights', 'i')
        ->where('u.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id);
    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

the above only returns flight field of path in this case 123 when called with the below in controller

```
$restresults2 = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('MyBundle:Flights')
                ->findWithFlights($id);
$response = new Response(json_encode($restresults2));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

return $response;
```

editted to show entity models

```
/**
 * Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\Repository\UsersRepository")
 */
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $email;

    getters and setters


/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Flights", mappedBy="users")
     */
    private $flights;


    /**
     * 
     *
     * @param \MyBundle\Entity\Flights $flights
     * @return Users
     */
    public function addFlights(\MyBundle\Entity\Flights $flights)
    {
        $this->flights[] = $flights

        return $this;


    }


    /**
     * Get flights
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getFlights()
    {
        return $this->flights;
    }

    /**
     * Remove Flights
     *
     * @param \MyBundle\Entity\Flights $flights
     */
    public function removeFlights(\MyBundle\Entity\Flights $flights)
    {
        $this->flights->removeElement($flights);
    }   



******************  Flights entity **************************8
/**
 * Flights
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="flights") 
 */
class Flights
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $path;

    getters and setters here

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="flights")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="usersfk", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $users;


    /**
     * Set Users
     *
     * @param \MyBundle\Entity\Users $users 
     * @return Flights
     */
    public function setUsers(\MyBundle\Entity\Users $users = null)
    {
        $this->users = $users;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Users
     *
     * @return \MyBundle\Entity\Users
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
```

Please what could be wrong with my repo query

Comment: Should you not have a join table for the many to many relationship?

Comment: please show me.... if i have i would shown it

Comment: Please post your entity code for both entity `User` and `Flight`.

Comment: its been added please take a look

Comment: Sorry, I can not understand what exactly are you looking for? What is your raw data? what is your current result? what is your expected result?

Comment: this is my current result [
    {
        "path": "1234"
    }
]

Comment: you can see that the user fields is not there

Comment: USer fields are not there cause by default doctrine is fetching only entity data that belongs to the corresponding repository. Add ->select statement to show ORm what you wan't to fetch. I believe in your case it would be ->select(['u', 'i'])

Comment: Please post an answer to this thanks

Comment: Posted the answer below if this is what you wanted you can mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are some things wrong here. But first of all, you should ask yourself: should users and flight not have a many-to-many realtionship? In your current model one flight can only have one user, and the same user can be connected to many flights. Do you really want this?

Then when you query, you should ask yourself; do I want a result of users or a result of flight and create your query builder in the repository you want to have your results of.

If you want all the flights of a user this should be your query:

```
class FlightRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
public function findWithFlights($id)
{
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('f')
    ->join('f.users', 'u')
    ->where('u.id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', $id);
return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: I think the relationship of flight and users is a bi-directional relationship

Comment: Exuse me I looked it the wrong entity for your many-to-one, I'll remove that bit of my answer. But then it means one flight can only have one user! And the same user can be on more than one flight. But is this what you want?

Comment: Ok, so what exactly is the result of your query that you would like to have?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to find all flights of a user? See the update.

Comment: Entity\Users has no association named users (500 Internal Server Error)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176421/discussion-between-dirk-j-faber-and-rocket).

Answer (score 0):

User fields are not there cause by default doctrine is fetching only entity data that belongs to the corresponding repository. (select('u')).
Add a proper select statement to show Doctrine what you want to fetch.
I believe in your case it would be select(['u', 'i'])

```
class FlightRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
  public function findWithFlights($id) {
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
      ->select(['u', 'i'])
      ->join('u.flights', 'i')
      ->where('u.id = :id')
      ->setParameter('id', $id);

      return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
  }
}
```

Comment: please post complete repository